# Signing with a private key as a string in php

Tags: java, php, sign, php-openssl

I have a private key stored as a string (hard coded), and I need to sign a string with that key.

I could use openssl, but I don't find in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php%20documentation) how to use my private key. I only see how to use pem files, or things related to certificates, whereas my process has nothing to do with certificates or anything of the sort.

The private key comes from a Java desktop application and has been generated with the class [KeyPairGenerator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html)

```
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
        keyGen.initialize(512, random);
        KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey pri = pair.getPrivate();
        String base64Key = new Base64().encode(pri.getEncoded());
```

Does anyone have a hint on this ?

Thank you !

**Edit:** One of the private keys as an example :

```
"MIHGAgEAMIGoBgcqhkjOOAQBMIGcAkEA/KaCzo4Syrom78z3EQ5SbbB4sF7ey80etKII864WF64B
81uRpH5t9jQTxeEu0ImbzRMqzVDZkVG9xD7nN1kuFwIVAJYu3cw2nLqOuyYO5rahJtk0bjjFAkBn
hHGyepz0TukaScUUfbGpqvJE8FpDTWSGkx0tFCcbnjUDC3H9c9oXkGmzLik1Yw4cIGI1TQ2iCmxB
blC+eUykBBYCFFVbS2ccW7j+SMOiro2PzB1FG/TL"
```

It is the Base64 representation of the key.

My current code saving the key in a file named pem :

```
$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private("key.pem");
echo openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid);
echo "<br/>";
echo $signature;
```

But openssl_sign doesn't echo anything, even false as it is supposed to in case of failure...

Comment: What does your key look like?

Comment: I added a sample key in my question.

Comment: Tried saving data to file?

Comment: But it's not pem formatted ? Ok, I'll try.

Comment: Ok, it totally doesn't work, whatever I try. I also tried to format the key by putting the -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- and all, but I just get `supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key`. I'm desperate...

Comment: If it's not PEM-formatted, then putting it in a file called "pem" won't help, nor will adding headers. You'll need to get the key output in the right format. You might want to also include the code used to generate the key and tag it Java as well.

Comment: Thanks for advices. I applied them. I know it's not pem formatted but Justinas proposed to save it as a file, so I did it.

Comment: That *looks* like PEM data, except the Base64 encoding is all weird.

Comment: Hum, let me check that the Base64 library I'm using gives back the same result as other ones. The alphabet could be arranged differently.

Comment: @duskwuff ok, I checked the new key with 3 different Base64 libraries. So I'm sure that, at least this one, doesn't have a Base64 issue. By the way, shoudl I use the alphabet with - and _ (base64url) or with / and + ?

Comment: `pri.getFormat()` will tell you what kind of private key you're getting. That should help figure out how to deal with it in PHP.

Comment: it returns PKCS#8.