# DSA algorithm : Sign in PHP

Tags: php, sign, php-openssl

I need to sign a data on my server in php, and verify the signed data on my Java desktop application. My issue is that I don't succeed to generate a key that both languages accept...

My first try was to generate the key with Java [KeyPairGenerator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html), but as shown in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401519/signing-with-a-private-key-as-a-string-in-php), I couldn't make openssl to read the key.

Now I generated the keys with openssl like that :

```
$openssl dsaparam 512 < /dev/random > dsaparam.pem
$openssl gendsa dsaparam.pem -out dsa_priv.pem
$openssl dsa -in dsa_priv.pem -pubout -out dsa_pub.pem
```

I now try to sign something with this code :

```
<?php
$data = "test";

$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private("dsa_priv.pem");
echo openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid);
echo "<br/>";
echo $signature;
?>
```

Result ?

```
openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key in ...
```

What am I doing wrong ? Can anyone help me generate a working DSA key and sign something with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one important thing here. The `openssl_pkey_get_private` method takes either key as a string or a file with `file://` protocol. The following example works as expected:

```
$data = "test";

$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://dsa_priv.pem");
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid);
echo "\nSignature: " . base64_encode($signature) . "\n";
```

And produces:

`Signature: MCwCFBpkSESngh+6ooMQZj7i+76t87QmAhQJTfyvvoZ4YFPd722R2qRnXD/Giw==`

Comment: Ok, I'm leaving for one month right now so I can't really try, but I guess you tried it and it works. Thanks !